# Israeli on Shabbat-second day Yom Tov fulfilling locals' obligation

Tags: halacha, shabbat, eretz-yisrael, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz

I'm having a hard time constructing this hypothetical so I apologize if it feels forced or if the underlying halachic question could be generated more gracefully.

If an Israeli woman is being housed temporarily (for a week, unexpectedly, and assuming she follows the understanding that she only holds [one](https://www.aish.com/atr/Israeli-in-Diaspora-Second-Day-Yom-Tov.html) day of Yom Tov, though in this case that might only be manifested in her davening) with an American family (made of a father and two children) and she wishes to light candles on the Friday night which is also the second day of Yom Tov, what bracha does she make?

Is she lighting 'on behalf' of the family so she should include "v'shel yom tov' or does she light based on what she will be observing (shel shabbat)?

The same question might be able to be asked about an Israel man saying kiddush to be yotzei others in the same situation. For him, it is not Yom Tov and his [private](https://www.torahmusings.com/2016/10/second-day-yom-tov-israelis/) davening will reflect that. Which kiddush should he make -- one that represents his practice, or one that represents the practice of the ones for whom he is saying kiddush?

I am not expanding this to an Israeli who is asked to lead davening on the second day of Yom Tov but I'm not sure why -- my gut says that it is different but I haven't explored it yet.

Comment: The question of can they is different from the question of what text to use.

Comment: Is there any way the locals can fulfill their obligation for Kiddush for chag with a text that doesn't mention chag?? I don't know if the Israeli can say such a text for them, but clearly the Shabbat only text wouldn't work.